# CSRF invalid token for API call in Flask

Tags: flask, flask-restful

My objective is to build Rest API on Flask. When i send post JSON request to the server from Postman application http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/posts/add/post, I get "The CSRF token is missing" Error.

Respective route is here:

```
@api.route('/posts/add/post', methods=['POST'])
def add_post():
  subject = request.json['subject']
  body = request.json['body']
  myPost = Post(subject=subject, body=body, category_id=1)
  db.session.add(myPost)
  db.session.commit()
  return post_schema.jsonify(myPost).data
```

I have looked at different examples and nobody mentions about CSRF for such requests, as usually its used for WTF s.
Can you please advice, what am i doing wrong and fow to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this extract from the [docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/csrf/#html-forms), is it possible you are protecting your app like this?

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

Usually, you only need this for basic flask apps ([docs](https://from%20flask%20import%20Flask%20%20app%20=%20Flask(__name__))):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```